# In cppreference's description of std::basic_ostream, what does "constructing and checking the sentry object" mean?

Tags: c++

The documentation for [`std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>::write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) says [emphasis mine]:

> Behaves as an UnformattedOutputFunction. After ***constructing and checking the sentry object***, outputs the characters from successive locations in the character array whose first element is pointed to by s. Characters are inserted into the output sequence until one of the following occurs:
>
> - exactly count characters are inserted
> - inserting into the output sequence fails (in which case setstate(badbit) is called)

How am I to understand the statement in bold? What's this so-called "sentry object"?

As far as I can see, when `std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>` is called there must already exist an instance whose type is `std::basic_ostream`.

For example:

```
#include<iostream>
int main
{
    std::string str{"thanks for your attention to this matter"};
    std::cout.write(str.data(), str.length());
}
```

Notes: `std::cout`'s type is `std::ostream` and `std::ostream` is defined as `typedef std::ostream std::basic_ostream<char>`.

Comment: Did you click through to the page on [UnformattedOutputFunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedOutputFunction) or [basic_ostream::sentry](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/sentry) where itt describes what a sentry object is and does? Note that `basic_ostream::sentry` is a different type than `basic_ostream`

Comment: @NathanPierson Thank you so much. You save an hour! Since there is no such a direct link for `sentry` in the quotation, and I take it granted that `UnformattedOutputFunction`  and `sentry` are completely not related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the [*UnformattedOutputFunction*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedOutputFunction) link in the text you quoted, you will find the following description of what the sentry is and what it does:

> A *UnformattedOutputFunction* is a stream output function that performs the following:
>
> - **Constructs an object of type [`basic_ostream::sentry`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/sentry) with automatic storage duration, which performs the following**
>
>   - if `eofbit` or `badbit` are set on the output stream, sets the `failbit` as well, and if exceptions on `failbit` are enabled in this output stream's exception mask, throws `ios_base::failure`.
>   - flushes the `tie()`'d output stream, if applicable.
> - Checks the status of the sentry by calling `sentry::operator bool()`, which is equivalent to `basic_ios::good`.
> - If the sentry returned `false` or sentry's constructor threw an exception, no output takes place
> - If the sentry returned `true`, attempts to perform the desired output by inserting the characters into the output stream as if by calling `rdbuf()->sputc()` or `rdbuf()->xsputn()`. Additionally, `rdbuf()->overflow()` and `rdbuf()->sync()` may be called, but no other virtual member function of `std::basic_streambuf`.
>
>   - if an exception is thrown during output, sets `badbit` in the output stream. If exceptions on `badbit` are enabled in this stream's exception mask, the exception is also rethrown.
>   - If no exception was thrown, returns the value specified by the function.
> - In any event, whether terminating by exception or returning, the sentry's destructor is called before leaving this function.

Also, the documentation for [*FormattedOutputFunction*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedOutputFunction) (ie `operator<<`) has a similar description for its use of the `sentry`.

So, basically, every output method of `ostream` constructs an instance of the nested `ostream::sentry` class before performing the output work.  The `sentry` makes sure that the `ostream` is in a valid state to accept output data.  If it is not, the `ostream` is put into a failure state, and an exception is thrown if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much. You save an hour! Since there is no such a link for `sentry`, and I take it granted that `UnformattedOutputFunction ` and `sentry` are not related.

Comment: "*Since there is no such a link for sentry*" - start with the text you quoted. Follow the link for [*UnformattedOutputFunction*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedOutputFunction). Then follow the link for [`basic_ostream::sentry`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/sentry). Not that hard to find.

Comment: One more question arises, ***every output method** of ostream constructs an instance of the nested ostream::sentry class before performing the output work.* Why not construct a long time used `sentry` for every instance of `ostream` other than constructing a temporary `sentry` when every output method is called. The current implementation seems to be somewhat  of waste of CPU. How do you think about it? Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not supposed to persist between different invocations of an output method. The whole point is that there's necessary setup and teardown that has to happen before each individual method. This uses the ["resource acquisition is initialization"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) pattern so that even if the method exits with an exception, appropriate cleanup happens.

Comment: @John "*Why not construct a long time used `sentry`*" - because 1) the `ostream` doesn't know how many output operations you are actually going to perform, and 2) any individual output operation can fail. The validation is performed in the `sentry`'s constructor, so the `ostream` can only be validated 1 time per `sentry` instance. So a new `sentry` has to be created on every output operation. And no, it is not very wasteful of CPU. If you look at what the `sentry` actually does, it is a fairly light-weight class.